# Logging in sharepoint 2010

Tags: logging

How to log all sharepoint errors, workflow errors, custom code errors into one central place?

I checked this and seems a nice tool, is this saved on a databaase?  Can I enable/disable events, like verbose and warnings and only leave exceptions?
http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint by default logs all the errors into ULS logs typically stored in text files located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs.

Tools suggested by James are used to view the logs and most tools allows you to monitor the logs live or archived logs. Most tools would also allow you to filter. For example, you may filter on Level=Information to view verbose logs and level=high for error information.

If you are developing custom solutions on top of SharePoint, it will be your responsibiliy to log messages (with appropriate severity) in this log. I would suggest using a loggin framework that ships with SharePoint guidance: [The SharePoint Logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798395.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Your custom code should use the ULS to log errors.

To view errors, see this thread [List of tools for reading ULS logs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/list-of-tools-for-reading-uls-logs)

Answer (score 0):

There are many other good tools to recommend but to answer the question religiously based on my personal experience with this tool. I would say http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/ is really good tool to run on SharePoint application servers or Web Front ends. What I truly like about this tool is filtering of events and live logging as you perform farm operation.

Of course, you can also filter verbose and warnings,exceptions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage what gets logged by going to Central Admin - Monitoring - Diagnostic Logging. In here you can see everything that can be logged and the levels of logging.